# VB.NET specific string formatting

Tags: .net, vb.net, string-formatting

I have a string, lets call it "S" and it can be up to 8 digits log, and I want to align it in a string, and later in a text file to the right in 8 blanks (chr(32))

Ex. ( I put underscores in the example to mark the blanks.

```
S="1234"    should result in "____1234"
S="444444"  should result in "__444444"
S="abc"     should result in "_____abc"
```

For this I would write the following code

```
Public Function feld(ByVal S As String, Optional I As Integer = 8) As String
    Dim lenS As Integer = Strings.Len(S)
    Dim vorS As Integer = I - lenS
    Dim rez As String = ""
    For x = 1 To vorS
        rez += Strings.Chr(32)
    Next
    rez += S
    Return rez
End Function
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Seems to be a job for [String.PadLeft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padleft(v=vs.110).aspx) (Or PadRight)

Comment: S.PadLeft(8, "_"c))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're making this ***way*** too complicated:

```
Public Function feld(ByVal S As String, Optional I As Integer = 8) As String
    Return S.PadLeft(I)
End Function
```

One wonders why you even need a new function, unless you want behavior different from the what `PadLeft()` uses in the case where the string is too long... but if that's the case, we need to know what behavior you want in the question.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `String.Format("{0,8}", s)` to align input string at right side of the result which will contains 8 characters.

To align the input at left side, use a negative number in format.

For more information see *Controlling formatting* and *Controlling spacing* in [`String.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) method documentations.

Comment: This way, it's enough to pass negative or positive length to simply align left or right.

Answer (score 1):

Other solution :

```
Public Function AddBlanks(ByVal S As String, Optional L As Integer = 8) As String
    return Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(StrDup(L, " ") & S, L)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

(I hope you are using SQL if not just avoid this)

It would be easier later if you do this in SQL creating scalar-function and you need only left align so what I do is (below is just for executes having example, go and create function using below code):

```
DECLARE @StringValue varchar(8)='123'
DECLARE @totalStringLength As Integer=8
DECLARE @ReplaceChar As char(1)='_'

DECLARE @stringLength As int
DECLARE @NewString As varchar(8)
DECLARE @ResultVal As varchar(8)

SET @stringLength = LEN(ISNULL(@StringValue,@ReplaceChar))
IF @stringLength >= @totalStringLength 
Begin
    SET @ResultVal = @StringValue
End
Else
Begin
SET @NewString = REPLICATE(@ReplaceChar, @totalStringLength - @stringLength) + ISNULL(@StringValue, @ReplaceChar)
    SET @ResultVal = @NewString
End
select @ResultVal
```

Now, you can create a stored procedure or just call function where you are want the string value to be.

here I assume now you have created function something named as dbo.leftPAD, just use below code on command line

```
select dbo.leftpad(string.text,8,'_')
```

if this is not what you are looking than sorry and forgive for my bad English.

Thanks